# For loop variable scope

Tags: ruby, for-loop, scope

Using this example:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]

for elem in arr do
  puts elem
end

puts elem # => 3
```

The code outputs:

```
1
2
3
3
```

`elem` contains the value even outside the loop. Why? What is it's scope outside the loop?

Can anyone clarify please?

Comment: Since when a loop introduces a scope?

Comment: Does the variable `elem` have scope or not?

Comment: `for` is not recommended in Ruby code because it leaks the intermediate variable. Instead we use `each` or `upto` or `count` to iterate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is expected. According to the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-for+Loop):

> The `for` loop is similar to using `each`, but does not create a new variable scope.

Example with `for`:

```
for i in 1..3
end
i #=> 3
```

Example with `each`:

```
(1..3).each do |i|
end
i #=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `i'
```

If I'm not mistaken, *methods* (`each`, `map`, `loop`, `upto`) create variables scopes, whereas *keywords* (`for`, `while`, `until`) don't.

Answer (score 2):

The `for` statement defines the variable `elem` and initializes it with the value of the current loop.

To avoid this use [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-each):

```
arr.each do |elem|
  puts elem
end
# 1
# 2
# 3
# => [1, 2, 3]
elem
NameError: undefined local variable or method `elem' for main:Object
    from (irb):5
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Now the elem variable exists in the block only.

Answer (score -2):

You can declare your variable elem outside the loop scope. So, if we modify your example:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3];
elem;

for elem in arr do
  puts elem
end

puts elem # => 3
```